# I won first place in/at the contest, which is correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I was writing my resume and personal statement but I don't know whether my sentences are proper:

> 1. I won **the** first place/prize **in** the contest.
> 2. I won **first prize and first place** **in** the contest.
> 3. I won the Honorable Mention **at** International Interdisciplinary Contest in Modeling.
> 4. I won the 1st prize **in** Mathematics **Competition**.
> 5. I won the 3rd Prize **at** **the** Smart Car Invitation **Tournament**.

My questions are:

Q1: Do I need to put the word "the" behind "tournament/competition/contest" in my resume?

Q2: How to choose the right preposition ('in',  'at' or 'of')?

Q3: Do I need to put the word "the" behind "prize/place" in my resume?

Related Questions:

[Using "the" in this sentence: "I won the first place at the tournament"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73393/using-the-in-this-sentence-i-won-the-first-place-at-the-tournament)

["came in first place in a challenge" vs "came first " vs "won first place"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68839/came-in-first-place-in-a-challenge-vs-came-first-vs-won-first-place)

Answer (score 4):

You certainly need at least `a` when the exact event is not mentioned. Then you need a `the` where it is. Also `the` is not used for placement or mention:

**1** and **2** are correct if you mention which contest. You also need to mention what type of contest. This is the case for all your achievements.
I would drop the `the`.

**3** The `the` is not needed in front of *Honorable Mention* but you DO need `an` or `the` in front of *International Interdisciplinary Contest*

**4** no need for `the` in front of *1st prize* but `the` or `a` in front of +Mathematics Competition_.

**5** no need for `the`in front of *3rd Prize*

So

1. I won first place/1st prize in the 24th annual Beijing Math Contest.
2. I won first prize and first place in the XXX Contest.
3. I won Honorable Mention at The International Interdisciplinary Contest in Modeling.
4. I won 1st prize in The XXX Mathematics Competition.
5. I won 3rd Prize in the Smart Car Invitation Tournament.

Comment: You say there is no need for "the" in front of 1st prize but then you include it in your fixed sentences..

Comment: Read number 4 in your answer. You say " no need for the in front of 1st prize".

Comment: No problem, I was re-reading it like ten times to be sure I am not crazy :) Thanks for the answer btw, useful for me too!

Comment: Just thinking, why in no.1 there is "the 1st prize" and in no. 4 there isn't?

Comment: Because I missed it :)

Comment: Ah, I see :) So, "the" is omitted only when talking about the position/placement

Comment: In my opinion yes.

Comment: You can be "in" a contest or tournament if you're competing and "at" an event.  If you're at a tournament, you're referring to it like an event, and therefore it's implied you're not participating.  I would fix 5.

Comment: In the competition at the tournament ?